# Error: Unknown option '--output' React & Django

Tags: reactjs, django, webpack

In my package.json file I have:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development ./x/frontend/src/index.js --output  ./x/frontend/static/frontend/main.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production ./x/frontend/src/index.js --output ./x/frontend/static/frontend/main.js"
  },
```

and when I try to run this command: `npm run build` it shows me an error: `[webpack-cli] Error: Unknown option '--output'`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 11):

It is nothing to do with **Django**. It is **webpack** module.

Apparently you are using old version of **`webpack`**.

You have to use `--output-path` instead of `--output`.